# Is it possible to use MongoDB validators to check one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mongodb

I wonder if is it possible to include in the [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/index.html#schema-validation) rules to check one-to-many relationship. I mean to avoid insert documents that do not accomplish the one-to-many relationship.
Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about foreign key constraints, no, this is not functionality that schema validation offers.